# Update SQL using GET request in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, get

I'm trying to update a sql database in java, but it only works in navigators. I am using a GET request for that, because the hosting doesn't allow me to activate the sql remote access.

This is the java function:

```
public static void insertScore(String user, boolean win){
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection=null; 
        try {
            url = new URL("http://mypage/insert.php?user="+user+"&win="+win);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And the insert.php file, this file it's ok, but if it helps you:

```
<?php
if($_GET["win"]=='true'){
$sql="UPDATE Score SET  `Win` =  `Win` +1 WHERE  `User` = '".$_GET['user']."'";
}
else{ 
$sql="UPDATE Score SET  `Lose` =  `Lose` +1 WHERE  `User` = '".$_GET['user']."'";
}

$link = mysqli_connect('myhost','myuser','mypassword','mydb'); //everything ok here
if (!$link) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result=$link->query($sql);
?>
```

When I paste the link in safari `http://mypage/insert.php?user=Steve&win=true` the Sql database updates correctly, but I don't how to do this using Java, it doesn't update anything in the database...

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: (Also, even when escaping is fixed, this system is *very* easy to cheat and it violates the rule of GET being idempotent. I would suggesting looking to existing RPC/WebAPI frameworks [for which there is a Java client and PHP provider].)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you are using withe the [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) Design Pattern, with this code you can update a row in the database:

```
public class UserDao { 
// you need to call your Singleton Connection class:
  Connection con = MyConnection.getInstanceOf();

   // and then you write a method to update your object, here I'm updating a User Object:
    public void updateUser(User user) {
         try {
            String sql= "Update User  set username='"+user.getUserName()+"',score='"+user.getScore()+"' where userid='"+user.getUserId()+"'";


            Statement ste= con.createStatement();
            ste.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, downloaded a library and everything its ok
The code is:

```
public static void insertScore(String user, boolean win){
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        try {
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://mywebpage/insert.php?user="+user+"&win="+win);
        } catch (IOException | FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
```

Official webpage: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: IMO you are using a Tank to kill Ants

Comment: It's the first solution I found :/ any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: I changed it! now it's ok?

Answer (score 0):

With this i'm not using tank to hunt ants (I think)

```
public static void insertScore(String user, boolean win){



    URI uri;
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        uri = new URIBuilder()
                .setScheme("http")
                .setHost("mypage")
                .setPath("/insert.php")
                .setParameter("user", user)
                .setParameter("win", win+"")
                .build();
        System.out.println(uri);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
        CloseableHttpResponse response =httpclient.execute(httpget);
        response.close();
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```